# Python: Comparing two dictionaries to see if two separate values match

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, compare

I have two arrays of dictionaries, and I am trying to check if two of the values are an exact match to the values of the other dictionary, over each value, and then return the value of only that value, and only once. The method that I tried returned results much greater than the original array. An example is below.

```
first = [{“num1”: 1, “num2”: 2}, {“num1”: 1, “num2”: 3}, {“num1”: 1, “num2”: 4}, {“num1”: 2, “num2”: 5}]

second = [{“num1”: 1, “num2”: 7, “num3”: 10}, {“num1”: 1, “num2”: 3, “num3”: 8}, {“num1”: 3, “num2”: 4, “num3”: 5}, {“num1”: 1, “num2”: 2, “num3”: 5}, {“num1”: 2, “num2”: 5, “num3”: 11}, {“num1”: 1, “num2”: 8, “num3”: 9}]
```

This is what the arrays look like. What I’m trying to check is if the values of the second array match both entries of the first array, regardless of position, and then add that whole entry from the second array into a new array. So, after running, a new array would be created containing 2nd, 4th, and 5th entries from the second array.

What I tried was this:

```
for item in first:
    for entry in second:
        if item[“num1”] == entry[“num1”]:
            if item[“num2”] == entry[“num2”]:
                new_array.insert(len(new_array), entry)
            if item[“num2”] == entry[“num3”]:
                new_array.insert(len(new_array), entry)
        if item[“num1”] == entry[“num2”]:
            if item[“num2”] == entry[“num3”]:
                new_array.insert(len(new_array), entry)
```

However, when I run this, I get a massive array, way larger than the original array. I then removed all the duplicate values, and found that it was the same size as the original second dictionary, so it just indiscriminately copied every entry.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I typed this on my phone and the code thing didn’t work.

Comment: I just submitted a recommended edit that cleans up the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I got you right. Here is the solution.

```
    first = [
    {"num1": 1, "num2": 2}, 
    {"num1": 1, "num2": 3}, 
    {"num1": 1, "num2": 4}, 
    {"num1": 2, "num2": 5}
]

second = [
    {"num1": 1, "num2": 7, "num3": 10},
    {"num1": 1, "num2": 3, "num3": 8},
    {"num1": 3, "num2": 4, "num3": 5},
    {"num1": 1, "num2": 2, "num3": 5},
    {"num1": 2, "num2": 5, "num3": 11}, 
    {"num1": 1, "num2": 8, "num3": 9}
]


for s in second:
    s = list(s.values())
    for f in first:
        f = list(f.values())
        if f[0] in s and f[1] in s:
            print(s)
```

The code will check if both values in the second dictionary are also present in the first one.

Comment: Will this check that both values are present or just one or the other?

Comment: I got the point of the question. I ll Edit my code in a moment.

Comment: Also, would there be a way to check that the entries do not contain both?

Comment: I changed the code, you 'll get desired result once executed. It is possible to check if the entry doesn't contain both, just by adding "else" statement.

Comment: Hmm, the starting and ending arrays are still the same size, and it’s taking way longer to run.