# Python: Best way to check if a key value match exists between two dictionaries?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, compare, key-value

**edit**
I have 2 list of dictionaries and I am trying to compare the value of a key in the dictionaries `list_1` to see if it that value exists in the value of a different key in the dictionaries `list_2` as I iterate through list_2.

**Lists of Dictionaries**

```
list_1: {'Video ID': 12894, 'Title': 'Title 1'...}, {'Video ID': 128993, 'Title': 'Title 3'...}, {...}
list_2: ('post_id': 12894, 'title': 'Title 2'...,} {'post_id': 128993, 'title': 'Title 5'...,}, {...}
```

I would like to see if value of key `Video ID` in the dictionaries of `list_1` match the value of the key `post_id` in the dictionaries of `list_2`.

I am trying the code below from a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60439633/python-comparing-two-dictionaries-to-see-if-two-separate-values-match), but I am getting confused on using the keys to access the correct value.

***Code***

```
for s in dictionary_2:
    s = list(s.values())
    for f in dictionary_1:
        f = list(f.values())
        if f['Video Id'] in s and f['post_id'] in s:
            print(s)
```

Comment: Are you always comparing `Video ID` and `post_id` or could `post_id` be called `bob` or something?

Comment: I am always comparing `Video ID` and `post_id`.  They are the record id but just with different key names.

Comment: I'm slightly puzzled why the looping then... aren't you really just after `if d1['Video ID'] == d2['post_id']` ?

Comment: Correct, but (I could way off) I need to iterate through `dictionary_2` to check every `post_id` value to find the match for my specific value of `dictionary_1`.  So, if `dictionary_1` is 12894, I may need to iterate through 300 values of `dictionary_2` to see if it exists.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Umm... if you're only ever looking at the value for the `post_id` key then no - you don't need to loop. Or are you saying you have a list of 300 dictionaries of which you want to find a dictionary with a matching `post_id` ? eg: in your example - is `dictionary_2` actually a dictionary?

Comment: The keys in a dictionary are unique... so a single dictionary can only ever have one `price_id` or one `Video ID`...

Comment: Hi @JonClements, I used wrong terminology which made this confusing.  I have edited my initial post and I hope that is clearer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242551/discussion-between-jon-clements-and-user3324136).

Answer (score 1):

The `Best way` depends on what you're trying to achieve.

If you are looking for the most efficient solution given your context then **Solution 1** is probably the way to go since you will probably have a lot of `Video ID`'s and `post_id`'s.

However I'm putting my original solution as **Solution 2** as it could be helpful in understanding what's happening. I'm also putting **Solution 3** if you want to better understand how to adapt this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60439633/python-comparing-two-dictionaries-to-see-if-two-separate-values-match/60439907#60439907)

Here is the example data that I'm using for both solutions:

```
list_1 = [
   {'Video ID': 12894, 'Title': 'Title 1'}, 
   {'Video ID': 128993, 'Title': 'Title 3'}, 
   {'Video ID': 1233, 'Title': 'Title 4'}
]
list_2 = [
   {'post_id': 12894, 'title': 'Title 2'}, 
   {'post_id': 128993, 'title': 'Title 5'}, 
   {'post_id': 1235, 'title': 'Title 6'}
]
```

## Solution 1 (Creating a lookup table)

Credits to @JonClements

As @JonClements correctly pointed out the best solution (given your context) might be to create a lookup table by converting the `post_id`'s in `list_2` to a dictionary with all the `post_id`'s as keys.

- Create the lookup table by adding each `post_id` as the key and each dictionary in `list_2` as the value.
- Iterate over each `video` dictionary in `list_1`
- if the `Video ID` of that current dictionary exists in the lookup table
- Assign the matching `post_id` to a `match` variable that contains the dictionary of the matching post
- Check if the title of the matched post is the same as the video's title
- If they are not the same then update the `Title`

```
# Create a lookup table
post_lookup = {d['post_id']: d for d in list_2}

# Iterate over video list and print relevant matches
for video in list_1:
    if video['Video ID'] in post_lookup:
        match = post_lookup[video['Video ID']]
        print(f"Same ID {video['Video ID']} and {match}")
        if video['Title'] != match['title']:
            print(f"Outdated Title {video['Title']} and {match}")
            # do something to update...
        else:
            print('Titles match, do nothing...')
            # this else may not be necessary
    else:
        print(f"{video['Video ID']} Not found...")
```

## Solution 2 (using 2 for loops and range() function)

If you simply want to compare the `Video ID` of `list_1` to every single `post_id` in `list_2` (disregarding efficiency) then you could do the following:

- Use the [`range()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp) function to iterate over every dictionary in `list_1`
- Use the same function to iterate over every dictionary in `list_2`
- Check if the current `Video ID` of the current dictionary in `list_1` matches the 'post_id' of the current dictionary in `list_2`

```
for video in range(len(list_1)):
    for post in range(len(list_2)):
        if(list_2[post]['post_id'] == list_1[video]['Video ID']):
            print(f"Video ID:{list_1[video]['Video ID']} matches post_id: {list_2[post]['post_id']}")
            if(list_2[post]['title'] != list_1[video]['Title']):
                print('Titles do not match, please update...')
                # do something to update the video/post title
            else:
                print("Title's match, do nothing...")
                # do something else if the titles match
```

## Solution 3 (Adapted from [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60439633/python-comparing-two-dictionaries-to-see-if-two-separate-values-match/60439907#60439907))

- Iterate over each dictionary in `list_2`
- get the `post_id` for that current dictionary
- iterate over each dictionary in `list_1`
- if the `id`'s match and the `title`'s don't then print the item and do something to update the title

```
for dictionary_2 in list_2:
    s = dictionary_2['post_id']
    for dictionary_1 in list_1:
        f = dictionary_1['Video ID']
        if f == s and dictionary_2['title'] != dictionary_1['Title']:
            print(s)
            # do something to update titles
```